# Apache + File on mounted folder = Corrupted file

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mount, corruption

We migrated our LAMP Ubuntu 16.04 (Apache 2.4.7) to a new one with Ubuntu 20.04 (Apache 2.4.41).

Both with a drive mounted on /var/www/intranet/onyar.

With the new one, if I download a file from this mounted drive it's corrupted. With the old one it works. If I download with the old server it's ok. If I access via samba it's ok.

- http://newserver/intranet/onyar/test.xls => CORRUPTED
- http://oldserver/intranet/onyar/test.xls => OK
- \\newserver\root\var\www\intranet\onyar\test.xls => OK

So it seems a problem between Apache and mounted drive? If I try it with a file outside mounted drive (http://newserver/intranet/test.xls) it works OK.

I tested it with txt, office type and PDF files, all corrupted. HTML files works!

I put a simple 'test.txt' file with the string 'hola' inside and I open it with 'http://newserver/intranet/onyar/test.txt' the browser give me this:

```
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 09:38:46 GMT
ETag: "4-5b3e5adb1be88"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Thu, 26 Nov 2020 09:40:37 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain

holad_ip = dnsResolve(host);
    if (isInNet(resolved_ip, "127.0.0.1", "255.255.255.255") || isInNet(resolved_ip, "172.16.0
```

In fact, if i Ctrl+F5 the string after hola (d_ip = ...) changes sometimes:

```
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 09:38:46 GMT
ETag: "4-5b3e5adb1be88"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Thu, 26 Nov 2020 09:57:01 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain

holar.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.80.160.178 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
p>The document h
```

```
Last-Modified: Thu, 12 Nov 2020 09:38:46 GMT
ETag: "4-5b3e5adb1be88"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4
Cache-Control: max-age=1209600
Expires: Thu, 26 Nov 2020 09:57:01 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain

holaIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document ha
```

These endings seems to be from other files! Like Apache don't know when is the file ending and puts there some other stuff...

Reference:

- fstab: //onyar/dades /var/www/intranet/onyar  cifs  credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,auto  0  0

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I'm affected by this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900821

For me the solution is putting this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/intranet/onyar">
  EnableMMAP Off
</Directory>
```